# Write file in android with angular and ngCordova

Tags: android, angularjs, excel, ngcordova

I'm trying to download an excel file from a restful java service on an android device using angular.

I tried using the ngCordova plugin file transfer. Altough it comes off as a sucess, it doesn't save up in the location i provided.

```
        var obj = { // excel parameters };
        var sendData = JSON.stringify(obj);
        fileFactory.getExcel(sendData) 
                .then(function (data) {
                   //this getExcel call will give me a token, and with it i can then create a queryString 
                    var url = // queryString path with token
                    var filename = //name
                    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
                    var trustHosts = true
                    var options = {};
                    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            // my function reaches here but never saves anything                        
                        }, function (error) {
                            // Error
                        });
                });
```

EDIT: heres my permissions

```
  <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Do i need to do something with the result of the File Transfer call? All the examples i have read show nothing in this section of the code.

Any alternative ways to get the file from the url path is welcomed.

Edit2: 
i'm testing in an actual device, with android 6.0.1

Comment: do you have this permission: `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: yes i have, i also use the sdk version 22